# Gravitational potential at the centre of Earth

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-gravity, potential, potential-energy, planets

Why does gravitational potential at the centre of the Earth is finite i.e. $V_c=\frac{3}{2} V_s$, as at the centre $r$ becomes zero so applying $V = \frac{GM}{r}$ the result must be infinity.

Answer (score 1):

Earth is a solid sphere and hence gravitational potential inside a solid sphere is given by $$V=-\frac{GM}{2R^3}(3R^2-r^2)$$ and not $\displaystyle V=-\frac{GM}{r}$ which is true for $r>R$. [Check this](https://www.sarthaks.com/453807/obtain-gravitational-potential-field-intensity-point-homogenous-solid-sphere-inside-point).